# How to force Landscape Mode Unity3D Android Game?

Tags: unity, c#, android, mobile

I am developing a small side project on Unity that will ultimately be for Android but I cannot figure out how to force landscape on the device and when I have tried it out the game just goes all over the place! I am using Unity Canvas and have spent a long time with binding position points etc. but I cannot work it out! Could someone please tell me how to force the phone into landscape mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Unity, navigate to Edit -> Project Settings -> Player and choose the platform on the right. Android should be the 4th tab if you're using one of the latest versions of Unity. 
Open the dropdown menu Resoultion and Presentation, you can set it there.